# Rewrite the html tags for frontpage

Tags: views

I am using views for front page. I was able to customize some things.

But I have some `<h1></h1>` in the body of an article and for the frontpage I want to change that automatically into `<h2></h2>`. Is that possible with views and if yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are having issue with the content that is being printed on the front page.
Then you can create a `page--front.tpl.php` and print the variable according to the requiremt.

If `$title` gives you the `<h1>` and `<h2>` tags, then you can `strip_tags($title, 'tags that need to be maintained e.g. <a>')` to remove the tags.

If you have issues with views field label, you can use '**Rewrite the output of this field**' and '**Strip HTML tags**' to change the output mentioned in the image below:-

[image]

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a page display and set this page as the front page.
Under the advanced section in views there is a section called theme, next to that is a link called 'information'.
When clicking that you see a list of templates used by views. You can copy the one that is used for your frontpage and edit that.

for example views-view--page.tpl.php, is listed in one of my views.
I would copy that name and make a new tpl file in my theme. Then copy the content of a template higher up in the hiarchy of the list this tpl name was in and put it in the new tpl. Then you can change it to fit your needs